# How could the wight plan have worked considering the obstacles?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In S07E04-07,

> Team Jon decides to go north of the wall and capture a wight to show it to Team Cersei. They carry on with their plan and actually bring one to King's Landing.

However, in S06E10,

> Benjen said "The Wall’s not just ice and stone, Ancient spells were carved into its foundation. Strong magic. To protect men from what lies beyond. And while it stands, the dead cannot pass. I cannot pass.".

How could this plan even work?

Comment: My personal speculation is that Bran broke the spells by crossing the wall in the same way he broke the ones in the 3ER lair. I've also made the title a little more meaningful while being completely SPOILER FREE

Comment: Perhaps the dead cannot pass the Wall themselves, but they can be brought through the Wall by others. It is magic, after all.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Why didn't Coldhands cross with Sam then? (Or Benjen crossing with Bran?)

Comment: @Aegon: no-one drags Benjen! It’s unclear in the show what the heck Benjen is, and when he says he can’t pass, for all we know he’s talking about duty or destiny or something.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite He didn't have to come south forever. He just had to cross, fetch Bran and go back North. And he told Sam he couldn't do it, because of Magic. Either he was speaking the truth or he was just being lazy.

Comment: @Aegon: I can’t speak to the books — I’m only going on the TV series here, where Benjen never speaks to Sam. To your point, the character in question (is that Coldhands?) may also be mistaken.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Then I might be mixing them up. I need to rewatch the show.

Comment: @Aegon: There is, to be fair, a lot of book, and a lot of show. Ah! Okay, [in the show Uncle Benjen tells us what he is](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Benjen_Stark#Season_6) (I clearly need to re-watch it as well).  Again, he may not be aware that he could be dragged through the Wall (assuming the magic applies to him the same way it would a Wight).

Comment: @Aegon: How do we know that Benjen was (a) correct and (b) being honest? All speculative options: _(1) Benjen didn't want to go home and face his old brothers as a wight out of shame or fear of being attacked (2) Benjen wanted to stay beyond the Wall to be useful (he is a scout after all), but he thought Bran wouldn't have understood (3) Benjen was merely repeating a common misconception or something that was commonly told to NW recruits to help them ease their fear of the Walkers, but it is not true._ I can't prove any of these, but we can't be **sure** that Benjen's claim was correct either.

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/151646/21267)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Jon answered it in Season 7 Episode 5, when they were planning the Wight expedition and someone questioned feasibility of the plan:

> The first wight I ever saw was brought into Castle Black from beyond
>   the Wall.

So from that precedence, he was certain they could do it again. The first wight mentioned here are the ones Jeor Mormont brought in Season 1.

This is inconsistent however. Show adapted book scenes for Season 1 but in Season 7 they are making their own story. Doubt it will happen that way in the books.

Anyways, a speculation can be, as long as a Night's Watch man accompanies a Wight, it can cross. But then the question is, Why did Benjen think he couldn't cross with Sam?

The spells on the Wall seem to be tied to spells on Three Eyed Raven's cave as pointed out by Edlothiad, so it is possible that Bran rendered them useless. But then again, Wights did cross the Wall in Season 1, Long before Night's King touched Bran.

Also they had a ship, so they could load the Wight on the ship and circumvent the Wall.

As it happened however, they had air-support when Dany answered Jon's call. But Jon didn't know she would come when he was planning so it could not have impacted his planning.

Comment: Also wight =/= White Walker. Benjen seems to be closer to a White Walker than a wight.

Comment: @Skooba Indeed. I think whatever was _possessing_ the wights at that moment, went out of them when they were crossing the wall, and then gained remote access again. We will know when we know

Comment: Also, they made their way back on a dragon, who can just fly over/around any spell barriers.

Comment: @Annatar At the time of planning, Air-Extraction was not an option. Dany was not going to get them out so Jon couldn't count on it. Things turned out that way later but they didn't know it would happen quite that way.

Comment: @Aegon True, they probably had the ship as their main plan (if outright carrying the wight through the gates doesn't work). But they never had to test the limits of the barrier the way it worked out.

Comment: I'm not sure what's inconsistent in your eyes, @Aegon. In both cases (First Wights and the one Jon just brought across), they were brought through by men, not under their own power.  Whether those men needed to be of the Watch or not is valid speculation but doesn't alter the fact that a reasonable scenario exists (and could have been considered by Jon) where the dead cannot cross but can be brought.

Comment: @Paul Yeah I had a discussion on main body with Paul.D.Waite and it appears that I am mixing books canon with Show canon. I'll have to refactor it once I have the time to cross-reference the two and filter the show canon

Comment: @Aegon, I may be missing something, but I thought in both the show and books the initial Wights were brought to Castle Black by men of the Watch?  So how's the canon different as it pertains to this question?

Comment: @Paul That part is same. It's Coldhands which contradicts this. Coldhands told Sam that he can't cross, if Wights could be brought by NW men, Coldhands could be brought in by Sam right? And I don't recall how did show-coldhands (Benjen) act in that position and if he had a similar encounter with Sam or Bran. That's what I will have to look into

Comment: Some gaps that I'm seeing in the discussion here: (1) were the S01 bodies already wights at the time they crossed the Wall? (2) is Benjen's claim ever proven to actually be correct? (3) Even if Benjen knew that and was correct, is there any proof that Jon (or any of his Merry Men) know that?

Comment: @Flater They were already wights. They had blue eyes which is why the rangers took them inside. We only have Benjen's word for it. In the books Yes NW knows the magic in the wall (Though many think its just a tale), in show not sure. Which is why I need to refresh my memory

Comment: @Aegon could be as simple as the character not knowing, or that Benjen/Coldhands isn't animated under the same rules/conditions as the wights. He's not mindless, after all, so clearly there is some technical difference in the implementation of his Undead state.

Comment: @Paul Indeed, as Skooba said, he is more like the Others than the Wights.

Comment: @Paul He says "the dead cannot pass", so to me it seems he should fall under the same category as the wights. Aegon, they had blue eyes but weren't raised yet? Maybe there's a difference, they cannot be go south of the wall, be their dead bodies can before they're brought back? I can't remember exactly how Jon's first encounter with a wight went

Comment: @7hibault They were already converted into wights, their eye color had changed, their flesh was not rotting. That was why Rangers took them  inside. And yes what you say is a possibility, what I mentioned to Skooba in second comment. It could be that whatever was running them left their bodies temporarily. Once they were beyond the wall, they regained access and Wights rose.

Answer (score 6):

The last that we saw of the wight in S07E06, it was stuck to Drogon's spikes.

It's highly likely that Drogon flew over the top of or around the Wall before dropping off his passengers, which completely bypassed the issue of the wight passing the Wall itself and coming into contact with its magical properties.

However, they also had access to boats, as that is how they ended up transporting it to King's Landing. Had their plan succeeded, they would have had the time to bring a boat up from Eastwatch without having to worry about having to deal with the entire army of the dead, and they could have again simply gone around the Wall to avoid its magic.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no magic that prevents a living person from carrying a corpse (reanimated or not) across the wall. Because corpses were brought across in Season 1 we can even see that nothing prevents a Wight from being raised on the far side of the wall either.

I think one of two things is instead true:

1. The magic prevents the dead from willingly crossing the wall.
2. The magic prevents the White Walkers from crossing (Which Benjen is related to, as he was turned to that instead of being risen as a simple Wight.) A wight could, but the usefulness would be limited if the White Walkers couldn't oversee and direct them on the far side.